# Issues with R.java after installed ADT 8.0.1

Tags: android, aapt

When I installed a new version of ADT plugin, Eclipse doesn't allow me to run my project. There is a message in Problems: "Error executing aapt. Please check aapt is present at /media/DATA/Program Files/android-sdk-linux_x86/platform-tools/aapt", though it's there!  And also I have got such message in Console: R.java was modified manually! Reverting to generated version! But I didn't delete it.

I have installed Android SDK Tools r8 to be compatible with ADT 8.0.1.

Can anybody explain me what can I missed in the configuration of my environment? Thank you for help.

Comment: I have the same problem.  Cleaning the project didn't work for me. Even trying to run a new example creates the same error as above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete existing R.java file from your package, then clean your project (in projects menu there is option to clean) in eclipse, rebuild it.
It may solve your problem.